# Is it possible to send animation (such as "typing..." or "...") to the user from the bot server, while user is waiting for the response?

Tags: google-hangouts

When a user is waiting for the bot to respond to the queries, I want an animation like ("typing..." or just "..." like we see when some other Hangouts user types in hangouts window) just above the typing area in hangouts. Do hangouts chat support such kind of animation event to be sent from bot server?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code.I use this to show typing activity animation.

```
 public static async Task ShowTypingActivityAsync(ITurnContext stepContext, int delay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Activity typingActivity = stepContext.Activity.BuildTypingActivity();

            await stepContext.SendActivityAsync(typingActivity, cancellationToken);
            await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: delay);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but Are we sure that this snippet is related to Hangouts chats? I want animation to appear just above the typing area on the hangouts chat's bot window.Actual question is, that whether Hangouts bot client support this feature?